# Assembly - Label to Register

Tags: x86, nasm

I'm trying the call the label 'LBL' using MOV to BX

```
@loop:
    MOV [bx], LBL
    INC bx
    JMP @loop

LBL:
    ;Do something
    JMP LBL
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you're having with this piece of code? What is the assembler you're using? MASM? TASM? Other?

Comment: And what errors do you get, what is not working?

Comment: I'm using NASM and it can't compile the code because I'm trying to MOV [bx], LBL

I want that [bx] to commit LBL code

Comment: This is a question and answer site. You ask questions, we answer them. The defining characteristic of a question is that it ends with a question mark ('?', ASCII code 0x3F, on most keyboards it can be found right next to the right shift key.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the effective address of your label:

```
looper:
    lea bx, lbl
    inc bx
jmp looper

lbl:
;Do something
jmp lbl
```

Comment: Thanks but I receive the following error: "Invalid combination of opcode and operands"

Comment: That's not valid NASM syntax.  In NASM, `mov bx, lbl`.  Or if you like inefficient code, `lea bx, [lbl]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Load Effective Address" instruction:

```
LEA BX, LBL ;Load BX with the effective address of LBL
```